Using the same formatting for the extra page after a Part as for blank pages before Chapters
I am writing a document using my university's template, which includes a custom document class.
In this class, which is openright as it should, the usually blank page on the left when a Chapter starts is not actually blank, but there is a float for a something.eps image. So far so good.
However, I also need to divide the document in two Parts. In between a Part and a Chapter, latex generates a blank page, as it should. But I need it to contain the same float as the other blank pages preceding a Chapter. How can I do this?
This is the code in the .cls file:
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{
\put(-150,-200){%
    \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
        \vfill
        \centering
        \transparent{0.4}
        \includegraphics[width=0.85\paperwidth]{./something.eps}
        \vfill}}}

and then
\newcommand\blankpage{%
\null
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\addtocounter{page}{-1}%
\newpage}

Finally in the config.tex file there is:
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\cleardoublepage{%
 \clearpage\if@twoside\ifodd\c@page\else
 \null
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}
 \thispagestyle{empty}%
\newpage
 \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother

I tried to put \cleardoublepage after the \part{} inputs but it did not work, and I'm out of ideas. Thank you for your help
